# secondary jqgrid in edit form of primary

Tags: jqgrid, edit

I am currently attempting to add a secondary jqgrid to the edit form of the primary jqgrid and running into some difficulties.

What I'm attempting to do is have a primary grid that contains two columns - ID, Description.
When adding/editing one of the rows I would like to have a second grid represent the "ID" field allowing the user to search for a specific ID already predefined in another location.  The description field would be a normal edit field.

If this isn't directly an option is it possible to add a button in the add/edit form to display a second grid in modal form and then on selecting a row in that grid pass the selected "ID" back to the edit form?

Any suggestions / recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is an older post of mine however seeing how it's not answered I'll post the answer I finally figured out.

The key was a several step process

1. In the colModel define your subgrid fields using custom elements:

   `editoptions: {custom_element: MeasureCreate, custom_value:MeasureValue}`
2. The MeasureCreate(value,options) method inserts a new table into the edit grid

   `var el = document.createElement("table");
    return el;`
3. MeasureValue(value,options) returns the value of a var set by the subgrid

   `return selectedmeasure;`
4. In the edit/add options set an onIntializeForm method
5. In the onIntializeForm function create the new grid

   `$('{mygridcolumn}').jqGrid(........................................`
6. In the onSelectRow event of the new grid set your value when selecting the row

   `onSelectRow: function(ids) {selectedmeasure = ids;}`